# Need suggestion which one is better from two simple CSS

Tags: css

Guys I do have two very simple CSS doing same thing(creating a triangle), i Need your suggestion which one is better.

**Example 1**

```
.leftArrow { 
    border-right: 5px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    height:0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

In example above, i am trying to define border for right, bottom, and top separately. Now the problem is if i do need to change border from 5px to 10px. I need to make changes in 3 declaration.

So it's not good to make change every time in 3 declaration for a single change. Suppose i do have arrow for all(four) direction. In that case i do need to make change in 4 X 3 = 12 declaration.

It's very time consuming :(

**Example 2**

```
.leftArrow { 
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: #000;
    height:0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

In second example I'm defining border or all sides in first declaration "border: 5px solid transparent;". In second declaration i am replacing left border width from 5px to 0px. and in third declaration replacing right border color from transparent to black.

Now in my opening it's also not a good idea to define border width in first declaration and then change it in second.

Same situation for third declaration. I'm changing border color from transparent to black.

Please give me your opinion for this type of situation or if you do have any better idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Use http://sass-lang.com/ with variables.

Comment: Hi, is this one better then Less, suggested in other answer? Or are they basically the same thing? Thanks

Comment: Yep you are right but i want to use plain CSS without any JS :(

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10210974/383609) in that case. This is _easily_ possible without LESS or SASS.

Comment: Yep i know already but as i said i do not want to compile it or use any particular tool for every time and for every small changes :(

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you're problem is, that you don't wanna change the same things over and over again?
Then [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/) could be something for you, it also allows you to e.g. nest your CSS, the best thing is, you can either compile the Less CSS to "real" CSS or include the `less.js` and you don't have to compile it (but I recommend the first, so it will also work with browsers, which have JS disabled).

Comment: Yep you are right but i want to use plain CSS without any JS :(

Comment: As I said, you can compile the "Less CSS" to plain CSS and include it as normal in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
border: 5px solid #000;           /* Set base style */
border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0px;    /* All 5px except left */
border-color: #000 transparent    /* Top/bottom #000, left/right transparent */
height: 0px;
width: 0px;
```

The first line sets a "base" style that is overridden by the next two `border-` properties. You can use `border-width` and `border-color` to set different colours and widths for each of the four sides of the element.

The `border-color` property above sets the left colour to transparent, but because the left `border-width` is 0, it doesn't have any effect.

---

To make things even easier to change, do this:

```
border: 5px solid #000;           /* Set base style */
border-left: none;                /* Get rid of left border */
border-color: #000 transparent    /* Top/bottom #000, left/right transparent */
height: 0px;
width: 0px;
```

Now all you need to change is the first `border` property. The `border-left: none` takes care of making sure the left border *never* shows. You don't have to change

---

This is pretty much as simple as LESS or alternatives, and sticks to pure CSS.

Comment: In that case i do have to make change in 3 place in property too, if i do want to change rectangle from 5px to 15px :(

Comment: it's almost same i ask for. You not need to add second declaration. Because you already set width 5px in first declaration

Comment: The second piece of CSS is supposed to _replace_ the first piece I posted. You set the border style you want, then clear the left border, then set the appropriate horizontal/vertical colours. Now you only need to change one value; the `15px` on the first line.

Comment: It's good buddy but if you see my second example it's same :) But i don't want to overwrite property :(

Comment: So it is. I should pay more attention! Either way, you're only changing on number if you want to change the border width if you use your current/my second piece of CSS. I'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: In my above two example first one is to stop overwriting CSS property and second one is easy to edit need to make change only one place to change border width. So i asked which one is better

Comment: Ah, right. In terms of which is better, I'd say the second; there is less to edit to modify the look of the triangle, and it's still perfectly valid CSS.

Comment: Thanks Man my opinion is also same. I am voting on it. let's see which solution mostly guys think is good:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble visualizing what your are trying to do, but if I understood you correctly, you could do something like this to reduce code rewriting:

Define common arrow properties

```
.arrow {
    border: 5px solid;
    color: #000;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

And then turn off the borders where needed

Show the left and bottom border only on the left arrow

```
.arrow.left {
    border-right-color: transparent; 
    border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

That way you keep the basic styling in the .arrow block.

Comment: Yep dude you are right :). But it's when i need to use more arrows but, we are still doing same thing first defining a property and then replacing it. I appreciate your reply it's good :)

Comment: I have to say that I've never thought that replacing a property is something bad, but then again, I'm not a designer, I've mostly picked up css along the way.
I'd like to know if there is a reason someone would "frown" upon replacing properties.

Comment: @Tarun - "we are still doing same thing first defining a property and then replacing it" - that's why it's called Cascading Style Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
<div class="arrow arrow-left"></div>

.arrow {
    border:5px solid #000;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
.arrow-left {
    border-left:0;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    border-top-color:transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pdRYE/15/

In this case you have only one border-width declaration and you are using the second class only to hide the border you don't need.

Comment: But in that case i need yo use to much declaration and it's same thing i ask in question :(

Comment: You can use shorthand `border:5px solid #000;` and that is the most you can do - the second class can't be shorter than that. If that is still to much - CSS can't handle it better - use LESS or SASS. Or maybe I don't get what you are asking for...

Comment: yep you are right it can be achieve easily by LESS or SASS but i don't want to use any JS or third party plug-in.

Comment: @Tarun - Well that's it than - CSS has it's own limitations too.

Comment: Yep i totally agree :) that's why i asked for opinion i am gonna vote for it :)